# "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Tags: c#, wcf

Quando instancio uma classe ocorre este erro.

```
Classe : AnttLogDTO

using System;

namespace NewsGPS.Contracts.DTO
{   
    public class AnttLogDTO  
    {        
        public string jsonEnviado { get; set; }

    public string RetornoCheckin { get; set; }

    public string Chave { get; set; }

    public IdNomeDTO Cliente { get; set; }

    public string IMEI { get; set; }

    public int codigoTipoLogID { get; set; }

    public string placaVeiculo { get; set; }

    public string cnpjEmpresa { get; set; }

    public string latitude { get; set; }

    public string longitude { get; set; }

    public decimal pdop { get; set; }

    public DateTime dataHoraEvento { get; set; }

    public DateTime dataHoraViagem { get; set; }

    public string comentario { get; set; }

    public string tipoComentario { get; set; }

    #region resultadoOperacao

    public Guid? idTransacao { get; set; }

    public bool? isErro { get; set; }

    public DateTime? dataEnvioAntt { get; set; }

    public string Erros { get; set; }

    public int? codigoRetorno { get; set; }

    public string mensagem { get; set; }
    #endregion resultadoOperacao

    #region jornada

    public string cpfMotorista { get; set; }

    public int? codigoTipoRegistroEvento { get; set; } //jornada
    #endregion jornada

    #region parada
    public int? codigoMotivoParada { get; set; } //parada
    #endregion parada

    #region inicioFimViagemRegular

    public string identificacaoLinha { get; set; }

    public int? codigoTipoRegistroViagem { get; set; }

    public int? codigoSentidoLinha { get; set; }
    #endregion inicioFimViagemRegular

    #region leitorBilheteEmbarque

    public string bilhetes { get; set; }

    #endregion leitorBilheteEmbarque

    #region leitorCartaoEmbarque       
    public string cartoes { get; set; }
    #endregion leitorCartaoEmbarque

    #region velocidadeTempoLocalizacao      
    public int? velocidadeAtual { get; set; }

    public int? distanciaPercorrida { get; set; }

    public int? codigoSituacaoIgnicaoMotor { get; set; }

    public int? codigoSituacaoPortaVeiculo { get; set; }
    #endregion velocidadeTempoLocalizacao

    #region inicioFimViagemFretado     
    public string autorizacaoViagem { get; set; }
    #endregion inicioFimViagemFretado

    #region VendaDePassagem     
    public string CodigoMotivoDesconto { get; set; }

    public string CodigoCategoriaTransporte { get; set; }

    public int? IdPontoDestinoViagem { get; set; }

    public int? IdPontoOrigemViagem { get; set; }

    public string InformacoesPassageiro { get; set; }

    public string NumeroBilheteEmbarque { get; set; }

    public string NumeroPoltrona { get; set; }

    public string NumeroSerieEquipamentoFiscal { get; set; }

    public string PercentualDesconto { get; set; }

    public string PlataformaEmbarque { get; set; }

    public string ValorPedagio { get; set; }

    public string ValorTarifa { get; set; }

    public string ValorTaxaEmbarque { get; set; }

    public string ValorTotal { get; set; }

    public string AliquotaICMS { get; set; }


    public int? IdMotorista { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region cartaoEmitidoRecargaEfetuada

    public string DataVenda { get; set; }

    public string HoraVenda { get; set; }

    public string BonusRecarga { get; set; }

    public string CodigoTipoCartao { get; set; }

    public string NumeroCartao { get; set; }

    public string SaldoTotalCartao { get; set; }

    public string ValorTotalRecarga { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region avaliacao viagem

    public string tempoViagem { get; set; }

    public string tempoDescanso { get; set; }

    public string KmPercorrido { get; set; }

    public string TotalParada { get; set; }

    public string TotalJustificativas { get; set; }
    #endregion


    public string nomeMotorista { get; set; }

    public string NomeEvento { get; set; }

    public Int64? Identificador
    {
        get
        {

            return Convert.ToInt64(this.dataHoraEvento.Subtract(this.dataHoraViagem).Ticks);
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    static int getInteiro(string input)
    {
        if (input.Length < 1) return 0;
        int number = 0;
        bool result = Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
        return result ? number : getInteiro(input.Substring(0, input.Length - 1));
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Em qual linha está dando o erro?

Comment: quando instancia a classe, tipo `var c = new AnttLogDTO()`? sua classe não tem construtor, nada é feito na instância, não vejo como ocorrer um erro... pode colocar um exemplo de código e onde dá erro?

Comment: Dá pra escolher qual é a duplicata mais adequada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Refer%C3%AAncia+de+objeto+n%C3%A3o+definida+para+uma+inst%C3%A2ncia+de+um+objeto